# Declaring a foreign key on the same line as a field?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

This works, but is verbose:

```
CREATE TABLE located (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    container_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_l2c FOREIGN KEY (container_id) REFERENCES containers
);
```

This attempt:

```
CREATE TABLE located (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    container_id BIGINT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES containers
);
```

fails with:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FOREIGN"
LINE 3:     container_id BIGINT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES cont...
```

Is there a way of declaring the foreign key on the same line as container_id?

Comment: Reading the docs [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) will show you that you are using the table level form instead of the column level form. In other words lose the `FOREIGN KEY` part.

Comment: I need `container_id` to be indexed.  If I omit `FOREIGN KEY` how do I make an index for `container_id` (on a single line)?

Comment: The `REFERENCES` creates the `FOREIGN KEY` in the column form and neither creates an index. A FK is just that a reference,  not an index. If you want to create an index on located.container_id you will need to issue a separate `CREATE INDEX`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Remove the `foreign key` in the inline FK: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=25afd50273f75ac8a347fcb5f6d2a1ad